# Does a distribution exist specified by next Cumulative Distribution Function?

Tags: probability, reference-request

Cumulative distribution function:
$$F(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^m}\right), x\in (0, +\infty), m \ge 1$$
$F$ is monotonic, $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x) = 0, \lim_{x\to+\infty} F(x) = 1$

Probability distribution function
$$f(x) = F'(x) = \frac{m}{x^{m+1}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^m}\right)$$

Is it a valid distribution? If yes, is it known?

EDIT:
We can extend the distribution on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ by saying that it is zero if $x\in(-\infty, 0]$

Comment: The pdf would be given by the formula you describe on $(0,\infty)$ and would be zero elsewhere.

Comment: Any increasing right continuous $F$ with $F(x)\to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$ and $F(x) \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ is the distribution function of some random variable on some probability space. You may want to look up the Stieljes measure associated with a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: Thanks, does this distribution have a name?

Comment: Not that I know of. If I knew the name I would have posted an answer. Where does this CDF come from?

Comment: I ``cooked'' such distribution based on what I need. If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it. You gave a reference to the Stieljes measure which is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a subspecies of the [Inverse Weibull Distribution](http://www.wseas.us/e-library/transactions/mathematics/2008/theoretical.pdf) with a guaranteed life time parameter of zero.